# Cannot Access Tomcat 7 Admin when multiple webapps are installed

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat7

I installed Apache Tomcat 7.  During the install, it asks if I want to do a full install or if I want to install just the web service.  I chose to install the full package (Tomcat and a web service).  When it finished, I had a windows service I could start.  I could then view/use the web-based tomcat admin panel.

I shut down the service and re-ran the installer to setup an additional web service.  I will have a couple dozen web apps to setup.  During the install, I selected the "Web Service Only" so I could install the additional web app without installing Tomcat again.  The installation finished OK.

I checked the installation folders and see both of my web services setup in the webapps folder.  I start the tomcat service OK.  When I attempt to view the web-based admin panel for either web service .. the originally installed web service and the second web service, tomcat seems to hang.  When I attempt to shutdown the service, it doesn't shutdown properly and displays the windows error "unable to shutdown service".  Eventually I can kill the process.

What could be causing this issue?  I'm new to Tomcat on Windows so I apologize if I did not provide enough information.  The web-based admin panel DOES work when I have a single webapp.  When I have two or more webapps, the admin panel quits working (hangs).

Any ideas?

Comment: So do you have 2 Tomcat Servers running?

Comment: A single Tomcat running on 8090.  The admin panel shows fine at my.servername.org:8090/testws/admin.  My 1st web app is named testws.  When I install a second web app and restart tomcat, I'm unable to go to either admin panel:  my.servername.org:8090/testws/admin or my.servername.org:8090/test2ws/admin. Tomcat appears to hang.  There are two directories in the webapps folder, one for each webapp.  If I move the test2 webapp out of the webapps directory and restart tomcat, the originally setup webapp (testws) works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Tomcat install a separate service for each web application, then you should be able to control each of them separately. They will be running separate JVMs, separate Tomcat services, etc.

If you had instead intended to have a single service with multiple applications deployed on it, then it appears that you may have made a mistake and configured multiple services instead.

From the command-line, you can launch the Tomcat service manager and specify exactly which of the Windows Services you'd like to control. For example:

```
C:\path\to\tomcat> tomcat8w.exe //ES//MyService
```

(Where `MyService` is the name you gave to your Windows Service when you configured it.)

You can find more information on [Tomcat's Windows Service Documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html).